# Windows 7 - file sharing - ownership - How restrict OWNER's access over network to READ-ONLY (virus protection)?

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, virus

I have two computers connected together in a network at home. I log in with same name and password on both. In Windows XP, I was accustomed to giving each computer READ-ONLY access to folders on the other. REASON: If a virus got on one, it could not infect the other one.

But in Windows 7, I don't find the same distinction between LOCAL access by a user and NETWORK access by the same user.

A folder's OWNER has full control, even over the network.

Alternatively, I tested with "Administrators" as the owner, and gave my account only Read access. As expected, this means I have to "elevate" to Write to the folder. But again, I don't see a way to specify that LOCALLY I should be able to Write without elevating to Administrator. Too inconvenient.

This functionality is an ESSENTIAL aspect of protection against viruses over a network, so there must be a way to do it. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable simple sharing, then set the properties of the share (under the Sharing tab, not Security) to deny write access.

To disable simple sharing: Control Panel (Appearance and Personalizations) / Folder Options, View tab, scroll to bottom, clear the "Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended)" check box.

Comment: Verified that giving only Read Permission to my user name means my login from other computer cannot make changes, yet locally I can (because I am the owner / I created the folder).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: To be more clear, the permissions of the _share_ come before the permissions of the object.